# mapsjs-core.js:27 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, here-api

I need help

I work with the here map api I try to display the contours around a city and I have this as an error

```
const shape = res.response.isoline[0].component[0].shape.map(z => z.split(','));
```

here is the complete piece of code

const requestIsolineShape = options => {
const params = {
'mode': `fastest;${options.mode};traffic:enabled`,
'start': `geo!${options.center.lat},${options.center.lng}`,
'range': options.range,
'rangetype': options.rangeType,
'departure': `${options.date}T${options.time}:00`,
};

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
router.calculateIsoline(
params,
res => {
const shape = res.response.isoline[0].component[0].shape.map(z => z.split(','));
resolve( shape );
},
err => reject(err)
);
});
} ;

Comment: res.response.isoline or res.response.isoline[0].component is undefined

Comment: thank you @GoldenretriverYT , i just saw it (Uncaught TypeError: res.response.isoline is undefined)
how can i fix it

Answer (score 0):

Please double check in console(Network tab) of browser which parameters are sent to Routing isoline service and check the response.

It seems are you using Routing API v7.2 then please play with playground on https://refclient.ext.here.com/ - click there on "New Tab +"

Better solution if you switch to new version 8 of Routing API and use this service which direct integrated to JS API: https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.30.7/api_reference/H.service.RoutingService8.html#calculateIsoline

Example:

```
let routingParams = {
 'routingMode': 'fast',
 'transportMode': 'car',
 'origin':'52.5,13.4',
 'range[type]': 'time',
 'range[values]': '900',
};

// Define a callback function to process the routing response
let onResult = function(result) {
  if (result.isolines.length) {
    result.isolines[0].polygons.forEach((polygon) => {
        // Create a linestring to use as a point source for the isoline
        const linestring = H.geo.LineString.fromFlexiblePolyline(polygon.outer);

        // Create a polygon and a marker representing the isoline
        const isolinePolygon = new H.map.Polygon(linestring, {
          style: { strokeColor: 'blue', lineWidth: 3 }
        });

        // Create a marker for the start point
        const isolineCenter = new H.map.Marker(result.departure.place.location);

        // Add the polygon and marker to the map
        map.addObjects([isolinePolygon, isolineCenter]);

        // Center and zoom the map so that the whole isoline polygon is
        // in the viewport
        map.getViewModel().setLookAtData({bounds: isolinePolygon.getBoundingBox()});
    });
  }
};

// Assumption: the platform is instantiated.
// Get an instance of the routing service
let router = platform.getRoutingService(null, 8);

// Call the Isoline Routing API to calculate an isoline
router.calculateIsoline(
  routingParams,
  onResult,
  console.error
);
```

Playground for v8: https://demo.routing.ext.here.com/